# Getting all tweets of an specific twitter account?

Tags: objective-c

I just want to fetch all tweets of an specific twitter account.
I want to use below url but don't know how we can get user_id or screen_name of a twitter account, whose tweets we want to fetch.

**Resource URL**
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.format
**Parameters**
Always specify either an user_id or screen_name when requesting a user timeline.

Does any one have any idea or source code or reference.
Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Welcome to the world of `UIWebViews`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set UIWebView's delegate to nil **before** navigating to the next view controller. Try to set

```
webView.delegate = nil;
```

at first in your IBAction